# The first item uploaded is deleted from mysql database when delete button is pressed in php page

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a page where i can delete item. It seems like it's working good but when i press the delete button it always deletes the first item uploaded by that user not the one i chose... Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Produktai</title>
<link href="CSS/stilius.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="CSS/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php require("includes/validate.php");?>
<?php require("includes/stilius.php");?>

<?php
$rec_limit = 4;
require("includes/connection_to_db.php");
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(P_ID) FROM prekės";
$retval = mysql_query($sql);
if(! $retval)
{ die('13 line. Nepavyko gauti duomenų: ' . mysql_error()); }
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM);
$rec_count = $row[0];


if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
    $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
    $offset = $rec_limit * $page;
}
else
{
    $page = 0;
    $offset = 0;
}
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

$sql = "SELECT prekės.* , CONCAT(vartotojai.name) as v_name
                    FROM prekės 
                LEFT JOIN vartotojai
                    ON vartotojai.V_ID=prekės.V_ID
                ORDER BY prekės.date
        DESC LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
$retval = mysql_query($sql);
if(! $retval )
{
    die('38 line. Nepavyko gauti duomenų: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['deleteItem']))
{
$P_ID = $_POST['P_ID'];
if(mysql_query("DELETE
                FROM prekės
                WHERE P_ID = '$P_ID'"))
{
    header("Location: products.php");
}
else {echo "Prekės nepavyko ištrinti: " .mysql_error();}

}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) : ?>

    <?php $image = '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" name="pix" width="270" height="200"/></td>' ?>
        <table class="two">
            <th><?php $pav = $row['name']; echo "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?product=$pav\">$pav</a>" ?></th>
            <th>Prekės savininkas: <?php echo $row['v_name']?></th>
        <?php if($row['V_ID'] != $_SESSION['user_id']) : ?>
            <th><select name="mano_prekės" value="<?php echo $m_product;?>">
            <option value="">Pasiūlykite savo prekę</option>
            <option disabled>---------------------------------</option>
            <?php require ("includes/exchange.php") ?>
            </select>
            <input type="button" name="exchange" id="exchange" value="Mainyti">
            </th>
        <?php elseif($row['V_ID'] = $_SESSION['user_id']) : ?>
            <th>
            <input name="P_ID" type="hidden" id="P_ID" value=<?php echo $row['P_ID']?>>
            <input type="button" value="Redaguoti" id="edit_item">
            <input type="submit" name="deleteItem" id="deleteItem" value="Ištrinti" onclick="return confirm('Ar tikrai norite ištrinti šią prekę?')"></th>
            </th>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <tr>
            <?php echo $image?>
            <td><textarea disabled style="resize:none; background-color:white" name="about" rows="12" cols="65"><?php echo $row['specs']?></textarea><td>   
        </table>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</form>

<?php
if( $page > 0 )
{
    $last = $page - 2;
    echo "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$last\" style=float:left>Atgal</a>";
    echo "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$page\" style=float:right>Pirmyn</a>";
}
else if( $page == 0 )
{
    echo "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$page\" style=float:right>Pirmyn</a>";
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
{
    $last = $page - 2;
    echo "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?page=$last\" style=float:left>Atgal</a>";
}
mysql_close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If you see what i have made wrong, please tell me, cause it makes me a headache..

Comment: `elseif($row['V_ID'] = $_SESSION['user_id'])` is wrong - need `==` there.

Comment: changed that line, but still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you a lot of `P_ID` in a single form you can try two solutions

**Solution -1 :** separate form for each item. (in each while)

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <table class="two">
            <th><?php $pav = $row['name']; echo "<a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?product=$pav\">$pav</a>" ?></th>
            <th>Prekės savininkas: <?php echo $row['v_name']?></th>
        <?php if($row['V_ID'] != $_SESSION['user_id']) : ?>
            <th><select name="mano_prekės" value="<?php echo $m_product;?>">
            <option value="">Pasiūlykite savo prekę</option>
            <option disabled>---------------------------------</option>
            <?php require ("includes/exchange.php") ?>
            </select>
            <input type="button" name="exchange" id="exchange" value="Mainyti">
            </th>
        <?php elseif($row['V_ID'] = $_SESSION['user_id']) : ?>
            <th>
            <input name="P_ID" type="hidden" id="P_ID" value=<?php echo $row['P_ID']?>>
            <input type="button" value="Redaguoti" id="edit_item">
            <input type="submit" name="deleteItem" id="deleteItem" value="Ištrinti" onclick="return confirm('Ar tikrai norite ištrinti šią prekę?')"></th>
            </th>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <tr>
            <?php echo $image?>
            <td><textarea disabled style="resize:none; background-color:white" name="about" rows="12" cols="65"><?php echo $row['specs']?></textarea><td>   
        </table>
</form>
```

**Solution 2 :**  make delete as simple button and apply onclick event on it.

```
<input type="button" name="deleteItem" id="deleteItem" value="Ištrinti" onclick="if(confirm('Ar tikrai norite ištrinti šia preke?')){window.location.href='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>?deleteItem=true&P_ID=<?php echo $row['P_ID']?>';}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your form encompasses all of the items, so when submitted it sends the last one of the IDs (which is the first uploaded item since you're ordering them in descending order).

You will need to wrap each individual set of inputs in their own form.